# ROS Publisher Node

Tags: python, opencv, ros, rospy

I am writing a code to publish the frames from a video to a rostopic. While declaring the pub object it is giving me an error.

```
import rospy
import cv2
from std_msgs.msg import String
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image
from cv_bridge import CvBridge, CvBridgeError
import sys

class Video_Publisher:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pub = rospy.publisher('tennis_ball_image', Image , queue_size = 1)
        self.bridge= CvBridge()
    def framepublish(self):
        video = cv2.VideoCapture('video/tennis-ball-video.mp4')
        while not rospy.is_shutdown():
            ret, frame = video.read()
            #cv2.imshow("TennisVideo",frame)
            try:    
                ros_image = bridge.immsg_to_cv2(frame,"bgr8")
            except CvBridgeError as e:
                 print(e)
                 continue
            self.pub.publish(ros_image)
            self.rate.sleep

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node('tennis_ball_publisher',anonymous=True)
    frames = Video_Publisher()
    frames.framepublish('video/tennis-ball-video.mp4')
```

It is giving me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tennis_ball_publisher.py", line 33, in <module>
    frames = Video_Publisher()
  File "tennis_ball_publisher.py", line 11, in __init__
    self.pub = rospy.publisher('tennis_ball_image', Image , queue_size = 1)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'publisher'
```

Comment: Python is case sensitive: It is supposed to be `Publisher` not `publisher`.

Comment: I tried doing that, did not work though! I have used catkin build again which made that error go away. But now I am having a new error regarding the nparray as follows:                                 dtype, n_channels = self.encoding_to_dtype_with_channels(img_msg.encoding)
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'encoding'

Comment: I don 't have time now to take a more detailed look but I don't think you want to use `immsg_to_cv2` but instead `cv2_to_imgmsg`, right? Your input is a `cv2` image and the output an uncompressed image message (note there is also a compressed one!).

Comment: Yeah, got it. Such a silly mistake, Thanks a lot though!!

Comment: To help reduce the amount of unanswered ros questions, aide future visitors, & award you some rep, want to type up a quick answer-summary? In this case, it seems that difficult error msgs were the result of mixed up inputs/functions. (Aside from the publisher typo, that's kinda obvious)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python being case sensitive: publisher --> Publisher
and
cv2_to_imgmsg instead of imgmsg_to_cv2 solves the problem.